# MATLAB: adding element of vector until reach to a particular number

Tags: matlab, loops

I get stuck in one question in my textbook. The question is to determine the number of random numbers it takes to add up to 20 (or more).
I use a loop for this situation. I am not sure about my code below.

```
a=rand(1000,1)
count =1 
for(a=rand(1000,1))
   count = count + 1 
   sum(a((count),1))
   if sum(a(count),1)>20
       break 
   end
end
```

What I want to do is to add up the elements in that vector until it reaches   20 or more.

Comment: 1) use `for count=1:numel(a)` and drop the count= line and 2)use `sum(a(1:count))` instead and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

This option use a low memory

```
a = rand(1000,1);
Limit = 20;
Acu = 0;
N = 1;
while Acu < Limit
    Acu = Acu + a(N, 1);
    N = N +1;
end
disp(N-1);
```

Comment: The last line should be `disp(N - 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward method in MATLAB is to create a random list that is plenty long enough to have a sum much greater than your limit, then run the `cumsum` function on it to cumulatively sum the vector, and then just select the lowest elements of the original random vector based on the value in the summed vector.

```
limit = 20;

randnums = rand(1, limit*10);  % Create a sufficiently long vector of random numbers
sumnums = cumsum(randnums);    % Compute the cumulative sum of the random vector
limitedrandnums = randnums(sumnums<=limit);  % Select the values from the random vector based on the sum

disp(limitedrandnums);
disp(sum(limitedrandnums));
```